# Get information from one case to another

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm new using C++ and I need to pass some information or values from one case to another case in the same switch.

It's like I have the switch thing and I named case 1 and case 2. In case 1 I'm going to do some math operations with a variable that the user is going to give me.
Like if the input is 5 I'm going to add 6, then will be 11.
And in case 2 I need that information, I need the amount that case 1 already calculated.
But I don't know how to do it.
I prefer not to use switch inside another switch, idk if it works, but I can't use it.
Thanks.

Comment: Show your code. Consider using continue keyword.

Comment: You have the option of not using the `break` keyword at the end of each case, but with out code, I couldn't even tell you if that makes sense to do that. Could you add code.

Comment: This feels like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish in the bigger sense? Why do you need to "pass information between cases"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your motivation for this question is either that you want to avoid writing redundant/duplicate code, or that you want to minimize CPU cycles by not performing the same mathematical operation more than once.  The techniques described below try to address both of those concerns.

The first question is:  is your code supposed to execute both cases, one after another?  If so, you can do that using the switch statement's "fall through" feature, which is to say, by omitting the `break;` statement at the end of the first case, you can let the program's execution "fall through" to the next case immediately after the first case executes, like this:

```
int x = 5;

switch(someVariable)
{
   case 1:
      x += 6;
   // fall through!
   case 2:
      cout << "x=" << x << endl;
   break;
}
```

Or perhaps you want the more traditional pattern, where every `case` has a `break;` at the end and you only want to execute one of the cases.  In that case, doing this...

```
int addSix(int x) {return x+6;} // helper function

[...]

int x = 5;

switch(someVariable)
{
   case 1:
      cout << "x=" << addSix(x) << endl;
   break;

   case 2:
      cout << "y=" << addSix(x) << endl;
   break;
}
```

... avoids the need to write redundant code (i.e. you only had to write the code inside `addSix(int)` in one location), but it does mean that the code inside `addSix(int)` is executed each time the switch-statement is executed.  For trivial calculations that's fine, but what if your calculations were really computationally expensive, so much so that you want to avoid performing them more than one time whenever possible?  For that you can use a technique called *memoization*, which is really just storing the result of the calculation in a variable, plus setting a flag the first time you perform the calculation so that you can remember not to do it the next time:

```
void doReallyExpensiveCalculationOnce(int & x, bool & isCalculationValid)
{
   if (isCalculationValid == false)
   {
      x += 6;  // pretend this operation is really slow/expensive
      isCalculationValid = true;  // remember we already did the calculation
   }
}

bool isCalculationValid = false;
int x = 5;

for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
{
   switch(someVariable)
   {
      case 1:
         doReallyExpensiveCalculationOnce(x, isCalculationValid);
         cout << "x=" << x << endl;
      break;

      case 2:
         doReallyExpensiveCalculationOnce(x, isCalculationValid);
         cout << "y=" << x << endl;
      break;
   }
}
```

Note that even though the for-loop above causes the switch-statement to be executed 1000000 times, the *really expensive calculations* to update the value of `x` are only performed (at most) once.